# Using Web API with ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was going through a tutorial located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Note: the tutorial is using Visual Studio 2012 (i believe) and I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I am running Chrome.

It does not seem to recognize the jQuery file. Is it not loading in time?
Note: there is a jQuery tab in my screen shot with its content.

I get an error - Default:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined:

[image]

Here is the default.aspx page:

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Products._Default" %>
  
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript"> src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getProducts() {
            $.getJSON("api/products",
                function (data) {
                    $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.

                    // Loop through the list of products.
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        // Add a table row for the product.
                        var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' + val.Price + '</td>';
                        $('<tr/>', { text: row })  // Append the name.
                            .appendTo($('#products'));
                    });
                });
            }

        // Executes when the document loads.
        $(document).ready(getProducts);
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- A content server control that points to the master pages "content place holder" area (MainContent) where this content page will be placed. --%>   
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
    </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the Site.Master:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Products.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
            <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>

        <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
     
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                    <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>

             <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Products</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container body-content">                   
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <hr />
                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically you're adding jQuery twice, once in your Master page and again in your webform. This is well know issue would cause jQuery issues. In your webform move Javascript code in header section to the body. After doing that, you don't need to add jQuery library in webform, as it is being added by Master.

Comment: OK..works..thanks.